# Swagger2 > Document a SpringBoot MvcEndpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, spring-boot-actuator

I'm currently in the process of trying out `Swagger2` on my `SpringBoot` project (it works great), however, it only picks up my `@RestController` classes.

I was wondering:

1. Can it be used to pick up a `Spring-Actuator` [MvcEndpoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/MvcEndpoint.html)?
2. Can the `Swagger2` components (e.g. `/swagger-ui.html`, `/v2/api-docs`) be hosted under the [management port (e.g. `http://${management.address}:${management.port}`)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-customizing-management-server-address), instead of `server.port`?

**Application.java**

```
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**AdminController.java** (aka custom Actuator endpoint)

```
@Component
public class AdminController implements MvcEndpoint { ... }
```

**application.yml**

```
server.port: 8080
management.address: 127.0.0.1
management.port: 8081
```

**build.gradle**

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.5.0"
compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.5.0"
```

**Versions:**

- SpringBoot: `1.4.0.RELEASE`
- Gradle: `3.0`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is eaiser to customize it to pick the "spring-boot-starter-actuator" exprosed endpoints.

The key point is add the customerize `RequestHandlerSelectors` predicate, the `com.example.Swagger2Config.RequestHandlerSelectors` is a good example to starter.

Following is the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class Swagger2Config {
    @Bean
    public Docket actuator() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("Spring Boot Actuator")
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectorsExt.withInterface())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("App")
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    static class RequestHandlerSelectorsExt {
        public static Predicate<RequestHandler> withInterface() {
            return new Predicate<RequestHandler>() {
                @Override
                public boolean apply(RequestHandler input) {
                    return declaringClass(input) == EndpointMvcAdapter.class;
                }
            };
        }

        private static Class<?> declaringClass(RequestHandler input) {
            return input.getHandlerMethod().getMethod().getDeclaringClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can get the API in the swagger ui.
[image]

Here is the [demo](https://github.com/cloudhuang/spring-boot-swagger2) project in github.

2) I really don't know what your exact meaning of "address:port, instead of server.port", obviously it's hosted in "address:port" just like "localhost:8080", please append more info for this.

Comment: Hi Liping, I meant the [management port i.e. `http://${management.address}:${management.port}`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-customizing-management-server-address), which can be different from the `server.port`.

Comment: @NickGrealy I'm afraid you cann't do that.