# SpringBoot > Ability to configure the Management ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring-boot

The way I understand it, [`spring-boot-actuator`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.boot%7Cspring-boot-actuator%7C1.4.0.RELEASE%7Cjar) creates [it's own ApplicationContext](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1175879fcc5888b187bdec3b4e3794890589cf34/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L180-L183) for the management endpoints...

**Is there anyway I can configure the Management ApplicationContext, other than via the `management.*` properties? (e.g. manually, annotations, etc)**

I want to be able to:

- [Add `Swagger/SpringFox` integration for my custom MvcEndpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159998/swagger2-document-a-springboot-mvcendpoint)
- Get a reference to the underlying `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server`
- host webjars/static content
- etc

**Related:** [Swagger2 > Document a SpringBoot MvcEndpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159998/swagger2-document-a-springboot-mvcendpoint)

Comment: Posting two questions for the same problem is not recommended. It is better to update the original question to give more clarity on the context like you have identified here.

Comment: Thanks, from my point of view though, they're two separate problems.

Comment: Overall the concept is the same... Your first point here points at that question so there is already the association. Within the other question you are asking "Can the Swagger2 components (e.g. /swagger-ui.html, /v2/api-docs) be hosted under the management address:port, instead of server.port?" which is the same as point 3 here. The only difference is this has a broader more general scope about access to the separate context.